# What is the reaction mechanism for formation of alkene from vicinal dihalide in presence of zinc and alcohol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

I have proposed the mechanism that zinc gives its two valence electrons to the halogen so it leaves the electrons of carbon which get shifted to form π-bond and the other halogen is pushed out. Then what is the use of alcohol in this reaction?

[image]

Comment: Alcohol is merely the solvent, without it you do not get good contact between the reactants.

Comment: Then is my mechanism correct??

Comment: More likely is Zn inserting in the C-X bond, see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66124/reduction-of-alkyl-halides-to-alkanes  The alcohol is also acting as a proton source.

Comment: Thank you sir. You made my work easy . May god bless you .

Comment: Your mechanism leads to the alkene but it implies stereospecificity, which is not the case.https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja01138a042

Answer (score -1):

In the vicinal dihalide, the carbon develops a slight positive charge and the halogen develops a slight negative charge. Due to this slight positive charge of carbon, zinc with its valence electrons attack the carbon atom and then carbon breaks its bond with the halogen which develops -1 charge,zinc develops +2 charge and carbon develops-1 charge. The lone pair of electrons of zinc on carbon shift to form the π bond with other carbon and the halogen atom of the other carbon also gets released with -1 charge. Hence the alkene is formed and the Zinc with +2 charge and 2 halogen atoms with -1 charge form ZnX2. The alcohol in the reaction acts as a solvent for better contact between the reagents.[image]

Comment: Do you have any references for this?

Comment: @ You only suggested me this idea and I think it is correct.

Comment: This paper suggests that a radical process is involved in the formation of the alkyl zinc https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/15685551.2014.947550  beyond that I can find no established mechanism